# Sending two different mails to two different users in php

Tags: php, email

After successful execution of command I want to send two different mails to two different person through if else function in PHP. I am able to send a mail using below code. How to send another mail with different headers & contents.

```
// if new reservation has been successfully added to reservation table 
// send notification to admin via email
if($result){
    $to = $email;
    $subject = $reservation_subject;
    $message .= $reservation_message."\r\n\n";
    $message .= "Customer name:" .$provinsi."\r\n";
    $message .= "Special Request :" .$comment."\r\n";
    $from = $admin_email;
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n".
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: so whats the issue?

Comment: If you create functions that create those emails, all you need to do is create one function per template and call that function from your if/élse statement. No more need for long code blocks that way.

Comment: Do it all again with the new to-from-message and call mail again

Comment: `mail()` is just a function like any other, you prepare the parameters and call it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i do it again it send the mail but with content of above mail too

Comment: Then you have not changed the contents of `$to,$subject,$message,$header`

Comment: @coder I am not able to send mails with different content... If I repeat the code it send the above mail content along with it. New to PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly do I need to change content all together? and repeating code means copying all if else and just replacing contents of it? right?

Comment: @TonyStark, becz you are setting the same parameters ($to,$subject,$message,$headers) in mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: @coder You are right I guess.. I will change the whole content and then try and See if it sends different mails.

Comment: it will ofcz send different mail dude. thats the logic

Comment: @coder Great buddy. I am learning PHP. I will try and revert.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need to do, just set the new reciever and sender and message and call `mail()` again

Mail is much like any PHP function, you set up its parameters and call it.

```
if($result){
    $to = $email;
    $subject = $reservation_subject;
    $message .= $reservation_message."\r\n\n";
    $message .= "Customer name:" .$provinsi."\r\n";
    $message .= "Special Request :" .$comment."\r\n";
    $from = $admin_email;
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n".
    if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
        echo "OK message 1 sent";
    } else {
        echo "FAILED message 1 sent";
    }

    $to = $email_2;
    $subject = $reservation_subject_2;
    $message = $reservation_message_2."\r\n\n";

    $from = $admin_email_2;
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n".

    if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
        echo "OK message 2 sent";
    } else {
        echo "FAILED message 2 sent";
    }


}else{
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly you have not cleared the scope of $message before the email 2 can use this , therefore content of email 1 will be added and send with email2  as you are using the string concatenation to exact variable

Comment: @TonyStark, which mail is not being sent? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: both. But when I remove     if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {;
        echo "OK message 1 sent";
    } else {
        echo "FAILED message 1 sent";
    } this it sends the mail but with above mail again

Comment: Tony That is not the fault of the code. I just added a test to check if `mail()` returned a good status. Did yuo receive mail form your previous attempt

Comment: Do you actually receive the mail you say is being sent

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes. previous attempts were successful.

Comment: Woops, TYPO Alert. THere was a `;` at the end of the IF line try removing and have another go

Comment: Does the second mail go to a different recipient?

Comment: yes second goes to different recipient but with other mail content. Removing typo and trying.

Comment: Did you also remove the first TYPO on the `$message = $reservation_message_2."\r\n\n";` line it was originally a `.=` and should be an `=`

Comment: yes edited the typos you suggested. Still not going. Not to anyone.

Comment: Hmmm dont make no sence

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result){
    createEmailOne();
    createEmailTwo(); 
}else{
    echo "Failed";
}

function createEmailOne(){
    $to = $email;
    $subject = $reservation_subject;
    $message = $reservation_message."\r\n\n";
    $message .= "Customer name:" .$provinsi."\r\n";
    $message .= "Special Request :" .$comment."\r\n";
    $from = $admin_email;
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n".
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "OK";
}

function createEmailTwo(){
    $to = "john@snow.com";
    $subject = $reservation_subject;
    $message = "Something went wrong in this form, here is the info: \r\n\n";
    $message .= $reservation_message."\r\n\n";
    $message .= "Customer name:" .$provinsi."\r\n";
    $message .= "Special Request :" .$comment."\r\n";
    $from = $admin_email;
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n".
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: @TonyStark You just create a new function with a different email address. Set `$to` to another reference or manually set it like `$to = "john@snow.com";`

Comment: Its not sending email. I have set $to reference to other mail. I am not receiving mail on either of the mail

Comment: Then something else is causing your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try This code :

```
function send_mail($to_email,$from_email,$subject,$message){
    $nameToBeDisplayed = "XYZ";
    $headers  = 'From: ' . $nameToBeDisplayed . '<' . $from_email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from_email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

    $message = "";      

    mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

if($result){
     send_mail('to1@gmail.com','from1@gmail.com','your subject','your message');

     send_mail('to2@gmail.com','from2@gmail.com','your subject','your message');
}else{
    echo "Failed";

}
```